# Convert string of words to a custom acronym/abbreviation in R and concatenate it with data from other rows?

Tags: r, text, bibtex, abbreviation

Here is an example data set:

```
data <- data.frame (author = c('bob', 'john', 'james'), 
                    year = c(2000, 1942, 1765), 
                    title = c('test title one two three', 
                              'another test title four five', 
                              'third example title'))
```

And I would like to automate the process of **making bibtex references**, e.g. with a function like this:

```
bibtexify <- function (author, year, title) {
      acronym <- convert.to.acronym(title)
      paste(author, year, acronym, sep='')
      }
```

so that I get the following result:

```
with(data, bibtexify(author, year, title))
[1] 'bob2000tto'
[2] 'john1942att'
[3] 'james1765tet'
```

Is it possible to do this in R?

Comment: There are [251 Q&A on *\[r\] bibtex*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+bibtex+), this could be a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you want `abbreviate`

```
R> abbreviate('test title one two three')
test title one two three 
             "ttott"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possibility you could build from:

```
title <- c('test title one two three',  
                              'another test title four five',  
                              'third example title')
library(gsubfn)
sapply( strapply(title, "([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]*"), function(x) paste(x[1:3], collapse=''))
```

This assumes that there are at least 3 words in each title, will need to be fixed if that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want an acronym, and not an abbreviation you can use this functions:

```
acronymatize <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
  paste((substring(s, 1,1)),
        sep="", collapse="")
}
```

Example:

```
> acronymatize("One Two Three")
[1] "OTT"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
accronym <- function(x)
{
  s <- strsplit(as.character(x)," ")
  s1 <- lapply(s,substring,1,1)
  s2 <- lapply(s1,paste,collapse="",sep="")
  unlist(s2)
}
```

The answer by Patrick works when there is a single element to be made an acronym. However, if there are more than one elements to be entered then probably the above function may work better. Instead of choosing 1st element in the s I am converting the entire list into short-form.
I was using too complicated a method before I saw Patrick's answer thanks for the suggestion.